# WordPress plugin only for parent & child themes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a plugin called "plugin-1"

```
Plugin Name :plugin-1    
/*
 *
*/

if ( wp_get_theme() == 'theme-1') {
    //my plugin stuffs
}
```

And I have theme & child theme called "theme-1":

```
Theme Name : theme-1
Theme URI : theme-uri
```

And for eg "theme-1-child":

```
Theme Name : theme-1-child
```

The problem is I want to allow all my child themes to access the plugin "plugin-1"!!..

The case is my clients will create their own child but I need to allow to access the plugin!!

How can I do this? Kindly help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( wp_get_theme() == 'theme-1' || wp_get_theme() == 'theme-1-child') {
//my plugin stuffs
}
```

Comment: The case is my clients will create their own child "theme-1-child" just for reference